# TypeError: unbound method sadd() must be called with StrictRedis instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Tags: python, redis

I have the following in a python app:

```
from redis import Redis, StrictRedis

......
r = line.split(" ")[0]
StrictRedis.sadd('my_set', r)
```

I'm getting the error in the title. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, password=None, socket_timeout=None, connection_pool=None, charset='utf-8', errors='strict', unix_socket_path=None)

I think you have to create `StrictRedis` instance first

```
sred = StrictRedis() #with your parameteres
sred.sadd('my_set', r)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. If I create the instance in a function, does it cease to exist when the function is executed?

Comment: variables inside a function is of local scope(it can use inside that function only)